# Convet string to date

Tags: java, parsing, date

I have a string that contains date in this format`"2014-07-23T00:00:00-07:00"`
I need to get the date part of it as output.
 any of the formats dd-mm-yyyy, mm-dd-yyyy... etc

Comment: You can either a) cut up the string and re-arrange it or b) parse the string and reformat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
String dateTime = "2014-07-23T00:00:00-07:00";
String date = dateTime.split("T")[0];
```

date will now be "2014-07-23"

Answer (score 2):

Try a `substring` function to get the string you want.

for example:

if you want         "2014-07-23"

try:

```
 substring(1,10)
```